# Replacing certain characters of an attribute using a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I am using a foreach loop to modify the attribute `mobile` for each user in Active Directory. Here is the relevant part of my script (I used a random number for mobile just to test it):

```
ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{mobile = '456'}
}
```

What I want to do now, is to just change certain characters in *mobile*. To be specific: I want to change each "0" to "+49 " and every "/" to a space. How would you go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{mobile = '456'}
}
```

to

```
ForEach-Object {
    $mobile = $_.mobile -replace '0', '+49' -replace '/', ' '
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Replace @{mobile = $mobile}
}
```

Comment: I still get an error code; I updated my answer below to the new one. I hope you don't mind helping me out some more.

Comment: @ConstantinS. Presumably the data you feed into the `ForEach-Object` doesn't have a property `mobile`. You need to update your question with more information about your code and your data. Also, I believe I specifically asked you to edit your *question* for providing additional information, so why did you edit your non-answer instead?

Comment: Using your answer now, I have solved the problem. Thank you for your help, and sorry for the inconveniences, sometimes my reading comprehension is lacking.